# Novel where the protagonist (and other space-going agents) wear a clear amorphous “skin” or “hide"

Tags: story-identification, novel

May have been published by TSR, definitely a smaller (US — maybe game-related) publisher trying to establish itself.  I think the novel even opens with the scene where the protagonist gets his “suit,” which invades his nasal passages and mouth and forms a protective barrier.  Everyone in the service (society?) gets this suit.  It may have been symbiotic organism, not unlike Venom (Spiderman) or the symbiotic suit in Their Master’s War by Mick Farren — except this one was clear.

Standard paperback, aimed at adults, may have had a white cover.  Mid-1980s to mid-1990s. Used to see it in used bookstores a lot.

UPDATE: Defintely not Varley, although I have since discovered those stories (part on Ten Worlds) and enjoy them. Don’t think it was Janet Morris; I would have known her at the time, and it was a standalone novel.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Stardance or one of the sequels, by Spider Robinson? The "suit" is an alien lifeform. I think it was red thought, not clear.

Comment: I think there's something similar in Janet Morris's Kerrion Empire series. First book is [Dream Dancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_Dancer) but the suit wasn't in the first scene iirc.

Comment: @mkennedy The "mil-suit" gets fitted at the start of chapter 2 in Dream Dancer.... however it's a girl who endures the choking sensation as it gets fitted to her lungs etc . And it's a symbiote

Comment: Definitely clear, not Robinson or Morris.

Comment: Some of [John Varley's novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ophiuchi_Hotline) have people going into space with symbionts instead of spacesuits.

Comment: Been a long time since I read them, but IIRC Sheffield's *Trader* stories have a "chillsuit" that encloses people.  It's physical, not a forcefield like the Heinlein one, since the protagonist has to lift his feet off the ground so it seals properly underneath them.  I don't recall if it's clear though.

Comment: I don't recall it being organic / symbiotic, but the high tech folk in LeGuin's Rocannon's World have invisible skin Impermasuits. There's a TSR connection with a write up in Dragon Magazine #54 https://annarchive.com/files/Drmg054.pdf

Comment: A few follow-up comments:
1) The writer was not well-known; I'm pretty sure it was someone I hadn't heard of before, and probably since. (Sheffield, Varley and LeGuin are well-known.)
2) I am pretty sure it was a first novel.
3) I tracked down the Varley stories, which are good, but it's not them.